# jquery order select box with numbers

Tags: jquery, sorting, select, numbers

I have multiple select boxes on my page and i want to order the options with numbers inside them from low to high but i cant get it working.

This is working when there is one selectbox on the page:

```
var selectList = jQuery('select option');
selectList.sort(function(a, b) {
      a = a.value;
      b = b.value;

    return a - b;
});
jQuery('select').html(selectList);
```

So i tryed this but this is not working at all:

```
jQuery('select').each(function(i, obj) {
    var selectList = jQuery('select option');
    selectList.sort(function(a,b){
        a = a.value;
        b = b.value;

        return a-b;
    });
}).html(selectList);
```

HTML (but then multiple of these with different numbers):

```
<select>
    <option value="">Selecteer</option>
    <option value="">1000</option>
    <option value="">43</option>
    <option value="">5356</option>
    <option value="">22</option>
    <option value="">6</option>
</select>
```

What is it that i am doing wrong? and is it possible that it alwasy put the first option als first? (so he skips the first option of the select)

Comment: can you share html ?

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj i edit the anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target content isn't **value**, but is **text**. So you should use `.text()` instead of `.value`

If you have one select element use

```
$('select option').sort(function(a,b){
  return $(a).text()-$(b).text();
}).appendTo("select");
```

```js
$('select option').sort(function(a,b){
  return $(a).text()-$(b).text();
}).appendTo("select");
$('select option:first-child').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">Selecteer</option>
  <option value="">1000</option>
  <option value="">43</option>
  <option value="">5356</option>
  <option value="">22</option>
  <option value="">6</option>
</select>
```

But if you have multiple select use

```
$('select').each(function(){
  $('option', this).sort(function(a,b){
    return $(a).text()-$(b).text();
  }).appendTo(this);
});
```

```js
$('select').each(function(){
  $('option', this).sort(function(a,b){
    return $(a).text()-$(b).text();
  }).appendTo(this);
});
$('select option:first-child').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">Selecteer</option>
  <option value="">1000</option>
  <option value="">43</option>
  <option value="">5356</option>
  <option value="">22</option>
  <option value="">6</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="">Selecteer</option>
  <option value="">1000</option>
  <option value="">43</option>
  <option value="">5356</option>
  <option value="">22</option>
  <option value="">6</option>
</select>
```

Note that if you want to set **first option** as `selected` use bottom code after sorting

```
$('select option:first-child').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Hi Mohammned, this is working thanks! But now when you first load it the last option  is visible in the select but how can you show the "Selecteer" option at first load?

Comment: No problem i found a solution also: jQuery("select").val(jQuery("select option:first").val());